# How to convert Depth Image to Pointcloud in ROS?

Tags: ros, point-clouds, depth-camera

I am using simulated kinect depth camera to receive depth images from the URDF present in my gazebo world. I have made a filter using python  which only takes a part of the depth image as shown in the image and now i want to visualize this depth image as point-cloud on rviz.

Since i am new to ROS it would be great if i could get some examples.

[My depth image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDUxg.png)

Answer (score 0):

have you ever tried this http://wiki.ros.org/depth_image_proc
also, you can find examples here:
https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline